# Python returns error "can't assign to function call"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I keep getting the same error.

This is probably a simple mistake, I just haven't coded in a while.

```
#import
import math

#initailse variables
float(x1)=0.0
float(y1)=0.0
float(x2)=0.0
float(y2)=0.0
float(complete_y)=0.0
float(complete_x)=0.0
float(final_decimal)=0.0
float(heading)=0.0

#get input
print("Welcome user!")
print("please enter your coordinates in format x and y including 
negatives")
x1=input()
y1=input()
print("please enter the coordinates of your target in the format x and y 
including negatives, you can obtain these from the map")
x2=input()
y2=input()
print("please hold for calculation")

#calculate
y2-y1==float(complete_y)
x2-x1==float(complete_x)
y/x==float(final_decimal)
math.asin(a)==float(heading)

#output
print("fire at a heading of", heading, "not including the negative if 
there is one")`enter code here`
print("press enter to close the programme")
```

Results in an error

> expected result is a heading in degrees.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. May I suggest that you take a couple hours revisiting the official Python tutorial ?  It should help refresh your memories and avoid wasting time on basic syntax issues ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are tying to declare the types before assigning values such as :

```
float(x)=0.0
x = input()
```

In python, the type is only known at runtime and you cannot declare type of a variable.

If you do :

```
x = 0.0
x = input()
print(type(x))
```

You will see x is a string, because you assigned a string with the `input` method. If you need a float, you need to convert it.

```
x = float(input())
```

As a side note,

```
#calculate
y2-y1==float(complete_y)
```

This code is valid if `y1`, `y2` and `complete_y` are declared before, it just returns a Boolean, `True` or `False`. And do not assign any values.

If you need to assign value, use a single `=` such as

```
complete_y = y2 - y1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do

```
float(x)=0.0
```

You're calling a function `float` on a value `x` and trying to assign `0.0` to the result of that call, which Python doesn't understand.  Python knows the type of `0.0`, you don't have to specify that it's a float.  Just do

```
x = 0.0
```

Also, I'm not sure what you expect your `#calculate` section to do, but at the moment it won't have any effect on the rest of the program in any way.